# tolower for C-style strings

Tags: c, string, tolower

I'm trying to perform case insensitive strcmp on two C-style strings.

I have a function to convert C-style strings to lowercase.

```
char* ToLowerCase(const char* str)
{
    char buffer[strlen(str)];
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(str); ++i)
        buffer[i] = char(tolower(str[i]));
    return buffer;
}
```

One string comes from function char* GetMyString(int i), and the second is in array of C-style strings char* myStrings[5].

So assuming that both GetMyString(0) and myString[0] both return "TEXT"

```
strcmp(ToLowerCase(GetMyString(0)), ToLowerCase(myStrings[0]));
```

compares strings like "mytextxaogs5atx" "mytextxabs5atx" (some random text gets added...)

whilst

```
strcmp(GetMyString(0), myStrings[0]);
```

works just fine, so that I assume there's nothing to do with the null termination as some of you might think.

What is wrong with my code? Did I miss something? I've looked at many questions about tolower but none of them were able to help with my problem.

Comment: You have undefined behavior, that's why.

Comment: If you have to use such function for a serious project, go for boost library to avoid different character set issues.

Comment: You are returning a buffer which becomes undefined after return.
what means `char(tolower(str[i]))`? `tolower(str[i])` should be enough

Comment: I'm just trying to make it work for past 2 days... I'm guessing something wrong with my buffer. I also tried doing this char buffer[strlen(str)]{}; but that also didn't help

Comment: "I'm trying to perform case insensitive strcmp on two C-style strings." -- Then at no point do you need to store the *whole* string as lowercase. You only need to convert the characters you're comparing at the moment to lowercase. Do that, and you no longer need an answer to this question.

Comment: @Holger, I'm casting it to char, since tolower returns me an int but my function should return a char array. So I either do (char) or char()

Comment: @hvd, nice! I'll try that right now and convert my ToLowerCase function to CompareCStrings! I'll get back later, thanks!

Comment: There's a function to do case insensitive comparisons.  On Posix systems you have `strcasecmp`.  Under MSVC, use `stricmp` instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Although the error in this question matches exactly the problem described in the famous duplicate, I think OP's question is less about "what's broken" and more about "how do I fix it".

Comment: @dbush I'm using MinGW so none of these ...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yep! I didn't even think of that, so every time I did a wrong search on "tolower". Maybe this thread will help someone else too!

Comment: @hvd you are genius. Thank you again! That's perfect :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return buffer;
```

You return a pointer to a variable that's local to `ToLowerCase`, the pointer will point to garbage after the call, resulting in undefined behaviour when trying to dereference the pointer. Either change the `str` itself or dynamically allocate the memory for `buffer`.

Comment: Wow I did not know that! Thank you for the answer with clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot return local variables from functions, so returning `buffer` is undefined behavior.

You have three choices to make this API:

- Take a non-const `str` and perform modifications in place
- Take a buffer for the string from the caller, and either assume that it has sufficient length, or also take the size of the buffer (much safer)
- Return a `malloc`-ed string. This would require the caller to free the result. Should you decide to go this route, note that you need to `malloc` `strlen(str)+1` bytes to accommodate null terminator.